# php array problem. please help me out 

Tags: php, arrays

$dir = "img/ori/";
$dir_thumbs = "img/thumbs/";

$images = array();
$d = dir($dir);
while($name = $d->read()){
    $thumb = "thumb_".$name;
    $images[] = array('name' => $name,'thumb_url' => $dir_thumbs.$thumb);
}
$d->close();
$o = array('images'=>$images);
i want to output $name and $thumb_url of all the images. how to do it.? help me